# Prove $x^2 + x \cos (x) -2 \cos ^2 (x) = 0$ has exactly two real roots

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, numerical-methods, rolles-theorem

> Given the equation $$x^2 + x \cos (x) - 2 \cos ^2 (x) = 0$$ prove it has exactly two real roots.

**My attempt**

In order two prove the equation indeed just has two real roots, first of all I need to prove they exists and then that they are the only ones.

For the existance part notice that denoting $f(x) = x^2 + x \cos (x) - 2 \cos ^2 (x) = (x-\cos (x))(x+2\cos (x))$
$$f(-2) = 0.0036 > 0, f(0) = -2 < 0, f(1) = 0.00045 > 0$$
By Bolzano's theorem, there is at least one root within each interval $(-2,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Where I am stuck is with the uniqueness part. I tried to find the derivate $$f'(x) = 2x + \cos (x) - x \sin (x) + 4 \cos (x) \sin (x) = 2x + \cos (x) - x \sin (x) + 2\sin (2x)$$
and putting it equal to $0$: $$2x + \cos (x) - x \sin (x) + 2\sin (2x) = 0$$
If I see that this equation only has a root (which is true, checked by graphing it), then by Rolle's theorem a function at most has one root more than it derivative; therefore the two roots I found are the only ones.

However, this is where I got stuck since I can't figure out how to solve this new equation. I think I may be going in the wrong direction, but I can't think of other way to solve the problem. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Hint…why not factorise first?

Comment: I factorised the equation as $(x - \cos (x))(x + 2 \cos (x))$, but I cant see how can it help to prove the uniqueness

Comment: Well, if $x$ is solution of your equation, the factorisation means that it has to be a solution of at least one of the equations $x - \cos(x) = 0$ or $x + 2\cos(x) = 0$, and so you are simplifying the problem by studying these simpler equations.

Comment: Why are you interested in finding the roots of $f'$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis It's a sound method in principle, since it's using Rolle's theorem. But it's painful in practice because of how sines show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorize it

$$(x- \cos x)(x + 2 \cos x) = 0$$

Let

$$g=x-\cos x,~~~~h=x+2\cos x$$

For $g$ part, if $x\in(-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty)$, then $g\neq0$. If $x\in(-1,1)$, we have $g'>0$, hence strictly increasing, and easy to check $g(-1)<0<g(1)$. Therefore, $g$ has a unique root on $\mathbb R$.

For $h$ part, if $x\in(-\infty, -2]\cup[2,\infty)$, then $h\neq0$. If $x\in(-2,2)$, we have $h'=1-2\sin x$. Hence $h$ is strictly increasing on $(-2, \frac\pi6)$, and strictly decreasing on $(\frac\pi6, 2)$, and easy to check $h(-2)<0<h(2)<h(\frac\pi6)$. Therefore, $h$ has a unique root on $\mathbb R$.

Last, check the two roots are distinct. Assume they are identical, we get

$$x+2x=0\Longrightarrow x=0$$

and apparently, $g(0)\neq0 \land h(0)\neq 0$, contradiction.

Comment: You still need to justify that those two roots are different, in order for the original equation to have two roots and not just one, but that's fairly simple since a unique root would imply having $x = \cos(x) = -2\cos(x)$, thus $3\cos(x) = 0$, hence $x = \cos(x) = 0$, but $\cos(0) = 1$, and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, I added it., thank you for mentioning this.

Comment: In the $h$ function I think there's a mistake since $$h(2)  =2 + 2 \cos (2) = 3.99 \& h(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2 \cos (\frac{\pi}{6}) = 2.52$$ You say $h(\frac{\pi}{6}) > h(2)$, and actually it is $h(\frac{\pi}{6}) < h(2)$

Comment: You make a mistake, note $2+2\cos2=1.17$ @IkerUCM

Comment: I'm sorry, my calculator was in degrees instead of radians......